# Facebook apps domain setting erroe

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

I tried to enter the domain while making facebook apps but the following erroe occurs.

Error
You have specified an App Domain but have not specified a valid integration URL.
rankfrod.com must be derived from one of: Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL.

What does this error tells, I have tried to enter a valid url i.e rankford.com,

Answer (score 0):

Well if you scroll down a bit in the settings page you will see,

> "Select how your app integrates with Facebook"

There you enter your URL for the integration and the app domain is derived from that one.

I.E

You're making an IOS Application, check the IOS Native Application, 
Enter Site URL as http://www.rankfrod.com and then in your app domain you can do appfrod.com.

Good luck!